# Handle SOAP BAD Request when request body contains reservered character like &,<,>

Tags: spring-boot

I am using micro-service architecture, where one microservice can calls other microservice to complete the request. My first microservice (say A) sending a soap request to my second microservice (Say b) when request body contains & or < or > then I am getting HTTP 400 .

Question: how to handle such characters parsing the response in B?

I am using SOAP 1.2 ,Spring Boot ,Postman to sending request to Microservice B as Microservice is not in my control.

Comment: It's not very clear what you want: the 400 error comes because the special characters, do you want to correct that or you need to report the error to the first service. In general it is recommended to escape special characters before the execution of the SOAP request to prevent malicious code / injection.